# png format images are not stored in my server

Tags: php, apache, image-processing

I upload images to my server using php script. I can only add jpeg format images to my server. 
I can't add png format images to my server. I didn't use any condition in my script. It could be all type of images. Anyone help me. This is the code i use. Files come from another page. Values ges to this page via jquery.
Where c3 is textbox name

```
$file_name1 = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/CDN/image/'.$t."1".substr($_REQUEST['c3'],strlen($_REQUEST['c3'])-4,strlen($_REQUEST['c3']));
file_put_contents($file_name1,base64_decode( str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '',$_REQUEST['c13'])));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES ('','".$_REQUEST['c1']."','".$_REQUEST['c5']."','".$_REQUEST['c6']."','".$t."1".substr($_REQUEST['c3'],strlen($_REQUEST['c3'])-4,strlen($_REQUEST['c3']))."','".$_REQUEST['c27']."','".$_REQUEST['c28']."','".$_REQUEST['c25']."','".$_REQUEST['c26']."','".$_REQUEST['c11']."','".$_REQUEST['c12']."',NOW())");
```

Thanks for your response.. I got answer. I use this code:

```
if(strpos($_REQUEST['c13'],'jpeg') !== false ) {
file_put_contents($file_name1,base64_decode( str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '',$_REQUEST['c13'])));
}
elseif(strpos($_REQUEST['c13'],'png') !== false ) {
file_put_contents($file_name1,base64_decode( str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '',$_REQUEST['c13'])));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? are you trying to process the image before storing it on your hard drive? If yes, what library are you using? and Do you have support for png files? Have you tried with different files, like .txt, .mp3, etc?. Are the .png files that you tried heavier (more Kb) than the jpg? what is the size (Kb) of the files? what is the upload limit that you have right now?

Comment: Wow, When I just saw the code I thought there was a formatting problem, but there is not, it's the way you wrote it. That's one of the most complicated codes I've seen lately.

Comment: How to add png format to this line base64_decode( str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '',$_REQUEST['c13']))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make your code a bit more clear, and help you find what is happening on your code, use the var_dump() to see the values.

Of course all the $_REQUEST and $_SERVER should be correct.

```
    // initialize variables
    $file_name1 = false;
    $document_root = false;
    $request_c3_len = false;
    $fragment = false;
    $mime = false;

    // check what information is available
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ) !== false ) {
        $document_root = dirname( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['c3'] ) !== false ) {
        $request_c3_len = strlen( $_REQUEST['c3'] );
        $fragment = substr( $_REQUEST['c3'],( $request_c3_len - 4 ), $request_c3_len );
    }

    if ( ( $document_root !== false ) && ( $fragment !== false ) ) {
        $file_name1 = $document_root.'/CDN/image/'.$t."1".$fragment;
    }
// var_dump( $file_name1 );
// exit( __FILE__.' '.__LINE__ );



    // work only if necessary
    if ( ( $file_name1 !== false ) && ( isset( $_REQUEST['c13'] ) !== false ) ) {
        $mime = str_replace( 'data:image/jpeg;base64,', '',$_REQUEST['c13'] );
// var_dump( $mime );
// exit( __FILE__.' '.__LINE__ );       
        file_put_contents( $file_name1, base64_decode( $mime ) );
    }
```

Check at each step that you have the information that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Actually my problem is i can't add png file because, i check only "data:image/jpeg;base64". Now i add another code for check png. My answer is represented above.